# Deleteing cache upon submit

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-3.5

I have an asp.net web form (c#, .NET framework 3.5) that returns to itself after the user clicks the submit button. I think that some values of the form are cached (some controls in a "placeholder" are out of position... meaning they have moved slightly up or down on the web form).

How can I delete the cache after user clicks submit, and ensure that the form reloads fresh, after submit?

Comment: What kind of cache are we talking about? Session cache, Global cache, the browser cache...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a `Response.Redirect` back onto the same page.  That will force a completely new page load.

Comment: I think it works! Holy Cow. What a simple solution. Thanks very much, Steve.